# how to store uploaded files for a web application while using AWS ECS FARGATE

Tags: javascript, python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am very new to the concept of AWS EFS.

As i am currently building a web application using Django/DOCKER with ECS - AWS Fargate backend and javascript with react front end, which is deployed to s3.

About the backend, I am wondering what would be the best way for a user to:

1/ store/upload the images related to their profile?

2/ assuming the user also own a product in the app and each product has images, how to store these images as well...

Would AWS S3 or AWS EFS be the most appropriate way to store 1 and 2 above?

Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is object storage, and EFS is a filesystem. There are [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30642879/248823) between the two, which can effect you decision based on the use-case.

But usually people store images in S3 as its cheaper and you can make them public (directly or through cloudfront) in case you want to display them on your website.